# How do I perform an id array query in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a model called `User`.
I have an array with object Ids.

I want to get all User records that "intersect" with the array of Ids that I have.

```
User.find({ records with IDS IN [3225, 623423, 6645345] }, function....
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to use the $in operator >

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

For example:

```
Users.find( { "fb" : { id: { $in : arrayOfIds } } }, callback );
```

Comment: But what's the syntax in mongoose?

Comment: it's the same syntax. `.find()` is a mongodb function.

Comment: Thanksk. What if my "id" is actually nested. The object is: { fb: { name:blah, id:blah } } . How would I query it by that id? Can you write it out for me? tanks.

Comment: `Users.find( { "fb" : { id: { $in : arrayOfIds } } } );` I haven't tested it but it should work

Comment: this is ridiculous, what if you're progressively building a query based on HTTP parameters and you have to check to see if they exist before you build the query?? like this `var query = Users.find(); if (x) { query.in(x) //?! }` ? will that work?

Comment: What's up with the "fb"?  This didn't work for me, but this did: `Users.find({_id: {$in:arrayOfIds} })`

Answer (score 85):

Here is a mongoosey way to use the $in operator.

```
User.find()
  .where('fb.id')
  .in([3225, 623423, 6645345])
  .exec(function (err, records) {
    //make magic happen
  });
```

I find the dot notation quite handy for querying into sub documents.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: I guess this should be the expected answer because it provides the answer with more clear syntax

Comment: Didn't know we could chain commands in mongoose ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

```
User.where({ records: { $in: [3225, 623423, 6645345] } }, function ...
```

more info here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/

Answer (score 0):

For me, work this way

```
IDs=["5b00c4b56c7fb80918293dd9","5b00c4b56c7fb80918293dd7",...]
const users= await User.find({records:IDs})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids is the array of object ids:

```
const ids =  [
    '4ed3ede8844f0f351100000c',
    '4ed3f117a844e0471100000d', 
    '4ed3f18132f50c491100000e',
];
```

With callback:

```
User.find().where('_id').in(ids).exec(callback);
```

With async function:

```
records = await User.find().where('_id').in(ids).exec();
```