# Mongoosejs find on array of objectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling with this since few hours now and hence posting here. I am trying to use find() operator in mongoose, to find whether a key matches any single element in the array, similar to [How do I perform an id array query in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818303/how-do-i-perform-this-query-in-mongoose-mongodb-for-node-js) but not getting expected results.

Here is my schema,

```
var a = new mongoose.Schema({
    b : { type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'B' },
});

var A = mongoose.model('A', a);
```

now I have an array , arr[], which holds some possible object id's of class B. i.e

```
arr = ["54e545fb6a0d90bb0772808b", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", ...]
```

I want to find all documents of type A, where the field b matches any of the elements in arr. Note that arr is an array of strings, but b holds ObjectId.

So far I have tried,

```
A.find({b : {$in: arr}}, callback); //and
A.find({b : {$in: new ObjectId("54e545fb6a0d90bb0772808b")}}, callback); //manually got this one value from db

var callback = function (err, data) {
        console.log("----------------------");
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));
        }
        console.log("----------------------");

    }
```

Both of these does not seem to work. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming arr is an array of strings representing ObjectId:

```
A.find({b : {
  $in: arr.map(function(o){ return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(o); })
}}, callback);
```

Comment: This still does not fetch any results. It returns an empty array

Comment: This looks like correct syntax. Are you sure an `A` with the right `B` `_id`'s in its array exists in the collection? What happens if you try a similar query in the mongo shell?

Comment: Ah..sorry. . this works. Turns out infact I was using the wrong id. Pardon my ignorance. Actually we need not even convert to ObjectId for it to work.